# open app on notification fcm without user reaction and automatically in ionic

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

how to open app automatically with notification fcm when app closed/killed in ionic?
I use `cordova-plugin-firebasex` and notif-data with force-start but not work.

Answer (score 0):

I change plugin and use of `@havesource/cordova-plugin-push`.
this plugin support `force-start` in noftification data FCM.